# What is the proper way to 'externalize' TimberSite methods?

Tags: wordpress, timber

I'm using Timber plugin, and I would like to have separate files for registering CPTs, taxonomies etc. I have a lot of those and do not want to clutter up the functions.php file. I know I can just use `require_once()`, but I'm not sure if it is the proper way.

```
class StarterSite extends Timber\Site {
    public function __construct() {
        ...
        add_action( 'init', array( $this, 'register_post_types' ) );
        ...
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function register_post_types() {
            // Proper way to have this data in a different file?
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing:

 `public function register_post_types() {
  require_once(CPT . 'init.php');
 }`